# Dropping items "in place" on Mountain Lion desktop

Tags: desktop

I run a multi-monitor setup at home with OS X ML as my main driver. Sometimes for a task I need to be able to drag-and-drop items from a folder to a particular spot on the desktop.

The problem here is that when I drag and drop an item on the desktop, it doesn't fall where the cursor is. It automatically gets moved over to the main monitor in the right column.  And I have to drag it back where I want it on the desktop. This is annoying.

How can I get osx to let me drop files precisely where the cursor is on the desktop?

Comment: I can confirm this behavior as well on 10.8.4 when I'm working in clamshell mode connected to an external display. I'll try and see if I can file a bug report as it seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the option `Snap to Grid` is not enabled.

Right click on your desktop to activate the window displayed in the screenshot.

[image]

I'm *not* running OS X Mavericks by the way; I'm just using the background :)

Comment: I tried that, but it still puts the files in a default column when I'm dragging them to the desktop. I can't believe nobody else has found this annoying or found a solution to this yet.

Comment: Joshua, are you on 10.8.4? You specified Mountain Lion, but did not say a version specifically. The reason I am asking is because of [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59874/how-can-i-make-files-i-drag-to-the-desktop-stay-where-i-put-them), which says that updating to the latest OS X *may* have solved it.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this earlier. Yes, I do have the latest version of Mountain Lion. It seems to happen when dragging from Most Apps including all browsers. It doens't happen when dragging files from the file finder to the desktop.

Comment: This has been happening to me as well. I'm also running 10.8.4, no updates available. I have not found any solution as of yet. Pretty lame!